# Can't upload image in Chrome

Tags: bug, status-norepro, google-chrome, uploader

I've just tried to insert a screenshot into my previous MSO question.

I get the dialog box for choosing to upload from my computer or the web, when I choose "My Computer" and click the "Choose file" button, nothing happens.

This is shortly followed by Chrome freezing and AdBlock reporting it has crashed. I then need to kill off Chrome and restart it.

Chrome freezes even if AdBlock is paused.
I'm using the lastest Chrome (22.0.1229.94 m) on Windows 7 Professional x64.

**UPDATE:**
Also get this issue on imgur.com, so not an MSO bug.

**UPDATE2:**
The issue was on my end, see my answer for full details.

Comment: No repro on the same version of Chrome on Mac OS X

Comment: What about other sites? Maybe your browser browse ability is damaged..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was discovered to be with our network.

Our NAS (Network Attached Storage) device was down and needed a reboot (1 of the drives is failing), this meant my mapped drives in Windows weren't responding and were timing out.

The file browser couldn't display until each mapped drive had timed out, which made it look like Chrome had hung or crashed.

Once the NAS device was rebooted, the file browser started appearing instantly again.

**UPDATE:**
The NAS was offline, but the file browser started appearing and responding correctly.
The NAs is now online again but I'm unable to re-produce the issue, so I'm putting it down to *something* when the NAS/mapped drive weren't online.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. please save the following code **as-is** to local file called "TestUpload.html" on your machine:

```html
<html>
<body>
    <input type="file" />
</body>
</html>
```

Then open the file with Chrome. (double click if it's the default browser)

What happens when you click the "Choose file" button?

Comment: It did work on Trello.com, but took a while for teh browser to appear. Chrome almost stopped responding aft the upload as well, but Chrome/Windows managed to recover itself.

Comment: Your code works instantly in Chrome! For imgur.com, the file browser comes up instantly in Opera.

Comment: Weird.. do you have any other plugins in Chrome? Maybe some anti virus program trying to "protect" you from malicious sites? imgur is blacklisted in many places as it host.. all kinds.. of images.

Comment: Just AdBlock and SpeedDial2, I'll do some more testing to try and narrow it down when I get some spare time. If it was the AV, surely this would affect Opera.

Comment: Not necessarily, AV software doesn't recognize all browsers, maybe they have their own "plugin" only for the major browsers.

Comment: Apologies, it's our fault, our NAS device (which hosts several networks services as VMs) was down this morning. Should I delete the question?

Comment: Hmm.. this might happen to others right? So please add this as new answer and accept it.